# Facebook Like Button for facebook post's permalink

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to make a Facebook Like Button for Facebook's individual page.

For example: http://www.facebook.com/michelleobama/posts/10150938120900578

I get the code from facebook developer's page, and put on it to a my html.

My html: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/188423/like.html

But raised a error.

So, I try to check the url by URL Linter.

It say "Facebook Can't Crawl Itself. Sorry!".

Dose it possible that I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Facebook won't scrape OG tags from Tab Apps. However you can let Facebook scrape Canvas apps (apps on apps.facebook.com). If you want to implement multiple Like buttons inside a Tab I recommend setting up simple HTML pages that include the appropriate OG tags as well as a redirect to your Tab in either a Canvas app (this way it feels like you're never leaving "The Facebook experience") or some external location (on your web server).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What dose "Tab" and "Tab Apps" mean? Is Obama's individual post a "Tab"?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You can't like individual posts via the like button.. sorry for the confusion. Just so you know though: "Tabs" are individual pages on Facebook fan pages that represent apps that have been associated with a fan page.